# Is there a way to abort the 'Payback' story mission?

Tags: far-cry-4

I started the story mission '**Payback**' in Far Cry 4, however I would like to abort it because:

> I believe it will remove Yuma and weaken her fortress, and I would like to liberate the fortress at full strength

I have canceled missions before from the <kbd>Escape</kbd> menu, but this time my only options are: "Resume" and "Restart Mission":

[image: escape menu]

I have tried:

- fast traveling
- starting a side quest (eg Kyrati racing)
- dying
- leaving the area
- exiting to menu
- exiting the game
- starting the game in online mode with the hope of inviting someone (anyone!) to the game, thereby disabling the campaign temporarily

Another user had this issue, but someone else [reported that "Leave mission" works for them](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/6mm32a/any_way_to_cancel_a_main_mission_far_cry_4/dk2prgr).

Is there something I have to do before I can leave the mission? I'm open to just about anything up to and including editing the save file*, if needed.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> Unfortunately I don't have a backup of the save, because it seems that Uplay keeps saves in its directory instead of `%USERPROFILE%` (*harrumph*).</sup>